# Infinite ListView of Images freeze app or throw exceptions during layout [small app included]

Tags: listview, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver, fitted-box

I'm trying to make a horizontally scrolling ListView with repeatable images to make it seem like it's one long image scrolling forever (like in 2d platform game).

[image: A symmetric Image repeated in a list view, resulting in a seemingly endless loop]

However, when I add images to the ListView.build(...) method I can't get them to scale properly.
I want the Images to `.fitHeight` and after trying all widgets I can think of I get one of two outcomes.

1. The app boots but freezes
2. The app runs but throws exceptions

Here is the code in its entirety:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    /// Freezes app and prevents it from hot reload/rebuild until app is manually terminated.
    Widget image = Image.asset('assets/repeatable-forest.jpg', fit: BoxFit.fitHeight);

    /// Wrapping Image in a FittedBox works, but with a lot of exceptions/warnings
    Widget fittedWrappedImage =
        FittedBox(child: Image.asset('assets/repeatable-forest.jpg'), fit: BoxFit.fitHeight);

    return ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      controller: ScrollController(),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return image; //fittedWrappedImage;  <-- choose which one to test.
      },
    );
  }
}
```

If you want to try it out with the example image (actually looks pretty good) you can download the "entire" repo here:
https://github.com/joelbrostrom/infinite_listview_image_freeze_example

As you can see in the code comments `Image.asset()` freeze the app and wrapping it a `FittedBox` makes it runnable but with exceptions.

In my main project the second approach builds with exceptions in debug congif, but freezes in release. Maybe that's a clue?

Here is the exception I get when wrapping the image in the `FittedBox`:

```
I/flutter (27099): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (27099): The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():
I/flutter (27099): 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 307 pos 12: 'width > 0.0': is not
I/flutter (27099): true.
I/flutter (27099): 
I/flutter (27099): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
I/flutter (27099): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
I/flutter (27099): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
I/flutter (27099):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
I/flutter (27099): 
I/flutter (27099): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (27099): #2      BoxConstraints.constrainSizeAndAttemptToPreserveAspectRatio (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:307:12)
I/flutter (27099): #3      RenderFittedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2288:26)
I/flutter (27099): #4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #5      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #7      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #9      RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:164:27)
I/flutter (27099): #10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #11     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:182:11)
I/flutter (27099): #12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #13     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:407:13)
I/flutter (27099): #14     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1322:12)
I/flutter (27099): #15     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1240:20)
I/flutter (27099): #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #17     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #19     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #21     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #23     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #25     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #27     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #29     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #30     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #31     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #32     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #33     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:142:11)
I/flutter (27099): #34     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:350:7)
I/flutter (27099): #35     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:212:7)
I/flutter (27099): #36     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:356:14)
I/flutter (27099): #37     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #38     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #39     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #40     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #41     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1206:11)
I/flutter (27099): #42     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #43     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #44     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #45     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #46     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #47     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #48     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #49     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #50     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #51     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #52     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #53     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #54     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #55     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #56     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #57     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #58     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3032:13)
I/flutter (27099): #59     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #60     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
I/flutter (27099): #61     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #62     __RenderTheatre&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #63     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #64     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #65     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #66     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #67     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #68     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #69     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #70     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #71     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #72     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (27099): #73     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (27099): #74     RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:151:13)
I/flutter (27099): #75     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1507:7)
I/flutter (27099): #76     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:766:18)
I/flutter (27099): #77     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:329:19)
I/flutter (27099): #78     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:701:13)
I/flutter (27099): #79     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:268:5)
I/flutter (27099): #80     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:988:15)
I/flutter (27099): #81     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:928:9)
I/flutter (27099): #82     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:749:7)
I/flutter (27099): #91     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19)
I/flutter (27099): #92     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)
I/flutter (27099): #93     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
I/flutter (27099): (elided 10 frames from class _AssertionError and package dart:async)
I/flutter (27099): 
I/flutter (27099): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
I/flutter (27099):   RenderFittedBox#fc66f relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (27099):   creator: FittedBox ← RepaintBoundary-[<0>] ← IndexedSemantics ←
I/flutter (27099):   NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ← AutomaticKeepAlive ← SliverList ←
I/flutter (27099):   MediaQuery ← SliverPadding ← Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#aa491] ← Semantics ← ⋯
I/flutter (27099):   parentData: <none> (can use size)
I/flutter (27099):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=1089.8)
I/flutter (27099):   size: MISSING
I/flutter (27099):   fit: fitHeight
I/flutter (27099):   alignment: center
I/flutter (27099):   textDirection: ltr
I/flutter (27099): This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
I/flutter (27099):   RenderSemanticsAnnotations#bfe63 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (27099):     RenderImage#90dc8 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (27099): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (27099): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFittedBox#fc66f relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (27099): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#4ba38 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (27099): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 467 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
I/flutter (27099): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'scrollOffsetCorrection' was called on null.
I/flutter (27099): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'debugAssertIsValid' was called on null.
I/flutter (27099): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'visible' was called on null.
I/flutter (27099): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'visible' was called on null.
D/libGLESv2(27099): STS_GLApi : DTS, ODTC are not allowed for Package : com.example.listview_image_scaling_issue
```

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hm... Docs say:

```
///  2. The [ListView.builder] constructor takes an [IndexedWidgetBuilder], which 
///     builds the children on demand. This constructor is appropriate for list views 
///     with a large (or infinite) number of children because the builder is called 
///     only for those children that are actually visible.
```

Which, in theory, should make it possible what you want to do. For whatever reason, you seem to run into a loop. `itemBuilder` keep getting invoked. My guess is that until the assets is loaded and actually rendered, it's dimensions can't be determined.

You  can verify this by setting an `itemCount: 1` and see the freeze gone. Also, setting an initial contraint on the width of the `Image` helps:

```dart
return ListView.builder(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
    return ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        maxWidth: double.infinity,
      ),
      child: Image.asset(
        'assets/repeatable-forest.jpg',
        fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
      ),
    );
  },
);
```

If anyone could provide some insight into why exactly `itemBuilder` keeps getting invoked, that's be awesome.